# typeerror: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list -flask and sqlacmey

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to python and trying to prevent unknown values being pushed into my database table named Tasks which isn't a value in my other table named Terms (querying by site_type with term_parent == "site_type").

When I try to loop the data from the Terms table and validate it against the input `task_site_type` I can only manage it not to throw an error if all the items are selected and if I swap the `if not` statement I get the error: `typeerror: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

Flask-sqlalchemy requesting the data which needs to be looped.

```
terms_site_type = Terms.query.filter(Terms.term_parent == "site_type").all()
```

Grabbing the POSTED list from the selected checkboxes.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     # Gather Form Input
        task_site_type = request.form.getlist('task_site_type')

e.g selecting two checkboxes task_site_type = ['Test1', 'All']
```

Closest thing i have to it validating
 error free - when i select all,
 `task_site_type` matches exactly as the loop from `terms_site_type`

```
for term in terms_site_type:
                if not term.term_title in task_site_type:
                    errors['task_site_type_list'] = 'Please select from list'



 e.g term.term_title(list) 
    Test1
    Test2
    All

 task_site_type - ['Test1', 'Test2' 'All']
```

ERROR
 form this setup which should validate what was posted against the database Terms loop

```
for term in terms_site_type:
                    if not task_site_type in term.term_title:
                        errors['task_site_type_list'] = 'Please select from list'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error from ...

```
                    if not task_site_type in term.term_title:
                        errors['task_site_type_list'] = 'Please select from list'
```

... is a valid error as the left operand in the `in` is a `list` and the right operand is a `string`. It shall be the other way round.

Also in your former code, I believe you shall be looping through `Tasks` and checking the list coming from `Terms` as that be the proper validation approach.

Correct approach will be something like below:

```
for task in task_site_type:
                if not task in terms_site_type:
                    errors['task_site_type_list'] = 'Please select from list'
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer shall do the job, but a better approach might be to get both the lists, convert them to sets and get the difference of tasks minus terms.

You may define a function like below:

```
def Diff(li1, li2): 
    return (list(set(li1) - set(li2))) 

Diff(tasks, terms) 
# if the resulting list is empty then the validation shall succeed
```

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-two-lists/

Finally, 
Even better approach will be to push the input list (i.e. tasks) in the query filter itself so that you bring the validation to the database itself instead of doing that in your code.